# Default privileges for object owner

Tags: postgresql, permissions, postgresql-9.6

We have doubts regarding default privileges for owner of objects. Let me show by example:

We start by creating a brand new role and schema:

```
psql (9.6.2)
Type "help" for help.

postgres=# CREATE ROLE bro WITH LOGIN;
CREATE ROLE
postgres=# CREATE SCHEMA bro AUTHORIZATION bro;
CREATE SCHEMA
postgres=# \c - bro
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "bro".
postgres=# SET search_path TO bro, public;
SET
```

We check the default priveleges and nothing shows up:

```
postgres=> \ddp
         Default access privileges
 Owner | Schema | Type | Access privileges
-------+--------+------+-------------------
(0 rows)
```

When creating a table, `bro` can access it by default:

```
postgres=> CREATE TABLE t1 (a integer);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> TABLE t1;
 a
---
(0 rows)
```

So we `REVOKE` the default privileges for `bro` on `TABLES`.

```
postgres=> ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES FOR ROLE bro IN SCHEMA bro REVOKE ALL ON TABLES FROM bro;
ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES
```

There's still nothing in `\ddp`, but we expect that `bro` won't be able to access the new tables we create:

```
postgres=> \ddp
         Default access privileges
 Owner | Schema | Type | Access privileges
-------+--------+------+-------------------
(0 rows)
```

We create a new table and `bro` is still able to access it, which seems wrong to us:

```
postgres=> CREATE TABLE t2 (a integer);
CREATE TABLE
postgres=> \d
       List of relations
 Schema | Name | Type  | Owner
--------+------+-------+-------
 bro    | t1   | table | bro
 bro    | t2   | table | bro
(2 rows)

postgres=> TABLE t2;
 a
---
(0 rows)
```

Then we try by explicitly revoking privileges from `bro` for that table and finally is no longer able to access it:

```
postgres=> REVOKE ALL ON TABLE t2 FROM bro;
REVOKE
postgres=> TABLE t2;
ERROR:  permission denied for relation t2
```

---

In the [PostgreSQL documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterdefaultprivileges.html) they state:

> As explained under GRANT, the default privileges for any object type normally grant all grantable permissions to the object owner, and may grant some privileges to PUBLIC as well. **However, this behavior can be changed by altering the global default privileges with ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES.**

Could someone explain if this is the expected behavior?

Thank you!

Comment: Why does it make sense to revoke all rights from the owner?

Comment: We may want a role for DDL only and others for DML. This question acutally comes from our `pg_dumpall` adding `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES` statements for the owner of tables, that does not make sense to us.

Comment: Try removing `IN SCHEMA bro` when you run the `ALTER DEFAULT PRIVILEGES`. Then run `\ddp` to see if it changes anything.